# creating pair RDD in spark using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

Im new to spark so I need to create a `RDD` with just two element.

```
Array1 = ((1,1)(1,2)(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)
```

when I execute groupby key the output is `((1,(1,2,3)),(2,(1,2,3))`

But I need the output to just have 2 value pair with the key. I'm not sure how to get it.

```
Expected Output = ((1,(1,2)),(1,(1,3)),(1(2,3),(2(1,2)),(2,(1,3)),(2,(2,3)))
```

The values should only be printed once. There should only be `(1,2)` and not `(2,1)`
or like `(2,3)` not `(3,4)`

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain the structure of your data in more detail to clarify exactly what the expected data should look like? Thanks!

Comment: For example, if input data was `(a,x),(a,y),(a,z),(b,x),(b,y),(b,z),(c,x)` what would the expected output be? How is the input mapped to the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the result you require as follows:

```scala
// Prior to doing the `groupBy`, you have an RDD[(Int, Int)], x, containing:
//   (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)
//
// Can simply map values as below. Result is a RDD[(Int, (Int, Int))].
val x: RDD[(Int, Int)] = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3))
val y: RDD[(Int, (Int, Int))] = x.map(t => (t._1, t)) // Map first value in pair tuple to the tuple
y.collect // Get result as an array
// res0: Array[(Int, (Int, Int))] = Array((1,(1,1)), (1,(1,2)), (1,(1,3)), (2,(2,1)), (2,(2,2)), (2,(2,3)))
```

That is, the result is a pair `RDD` that relates the key (the first value of each pair) to the pair (as a *tuple*). Do not use `groupBy`, since—in this case—it will not give you what you want.

Comment: Unless I misinterpreted the requirement, from the expected output `(1,(1,2)),(1,(1,3)),(1(2,3),(2(1,2)),(2,(1,3)),(2,(2,3))`, I don't think expanding `(k, v)` to `(k, (k, v))` is what OP wants.

Comment: @LeoC Good point. I missed that! But it's not clear (to me) exactly what he _does_ want... Having looked a little closer at the answer, I don't see a relationship between the input and the output, unless he wants every permutation of each pair of values with each key... What happens if there's only _one_ value for a given key?

Comment: Not entirely clear to me either.  If 2-combinations of values by key is indeed what OP wants, a key with only a value should probably be either discarded altogether or transformed to, say, (k, null).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you can use `groupByKey` and `flatMapValues` to flatten the `2-combinations` of the grouped values, as shown below:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, 1), (1,  2), (1 ,3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)
))

rdd.groupByKey.flatMapValues(_.toList.combinations(2)).
  map{ case (k, v) => (k, (v(0), v(1))) }.
  collect
// res1: Array[(Int, (Int, Int))] =
//   Array((1,(1,2)), (1,(1,3)), (1,(2,3)), (2,(1,2)), (2,(1,3)), (2,(2,3)))
```